# Observing all properties in a struct or class in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, key-value-observing

I have an iOS app in which I would like to use Google Cloud Firestore for storing user preferences, but I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant solution for calling my `saveSettingsToFirestore()` function after a change to any of the `Settings` struct's properties.

I certainly would prefer not to call my `saveSettingsToFirestore()` function manually after every instance in the app where I modify a setting. I suppose I could put a separate "didSet" property observer on all 15+ properties in this Settings struct but that would look ugly and I can't imagine that's a best practice.

I've considered KVO, but I can't find a good example that covers my case, and I'm having trouble setting it up.

Likewise, if you have a better solution to managing a set of vars associated with a user's account, please let me know. I am specifically not using NSUserDefaults because I want to associate data with a user ID, not the user's iCloud account.

Here is the struct I'm trying to observe:

```
struct Settings: Codable {
  
  static var shared = Settings()
  
  var hideTimesAfter = "10:00 PM"
  var hideTimesBefore = "5:00 AM"
  
  var increment = 15
  var nextColorIndex = 1
  
  var adsEnabled = true
  var alertsEnabled = true
  var bugShakeEnabled = true
  var didSeeIOSUpdateRequest = false
  var firstTime = true
  var isIdleTimerDisabled = false
  var notificationsEnabled = true
  var premiumEnabled = false
  var soundsEnabled = true
  var twentyFourHourModeEnabled = false
  var vibrationsEnabled = true

  private init() { }
}
```

And here's my attempt to restructure that `struct` into an NSObject `class` with an observer, but I'm still trying to figure out what goes where and would appreciate any insights.

```
class Settings: NSObject, Codable {
  
  static let shared = Settings()
  
  @objc dynamic var hideTimesAfter = "10:00 PM"
  @objc dynamic var hideTimesBefore = "5:00 AM"
  
  @objc dynamic var increment = 15
  @objc dynamic var nextColorIndex = 1
  
  @objc dynamic var adsEnabled = true
  @objc dynamic var alertsEnabled = true
  @objc dynamic var bugShakeEnabled = true
  @objc dynamic var didSeeIOSUpdateRequest = false
  @objc dynamic var firstTime = true
  @objc dynamic var isIdleTimerDisabled = false
  @objc dynamic var notificationsEnabled = true
  @objc dynamic var premiumEnabled = false
  @objc dynamic var soundsEnabled = true
  @objc dynamic var twentyFourHourModeEnabled = false
  @objc dynamic var vibrationsEnabled = true

  func updateDate() {
      print("yo firestore, get this shit")
  }
  
  let observed = Settings.shared
  let observer = MyObserver(object: observed)

}

class MyObserver: NSObject {
    @objc var objectToObserve: Settings
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    init(object: Settings) {
        objectToObserve = object
        super.init()
        
        observation = observe(
            \.objectToObserve.adsEnabled,
            options: [.old, .new]
        ) { object, change in
            print("myDate changed from: \(change.oldValue!), updated to: \(change.newValue!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are iOS 13 or higher, this is trivial with an ObservableObject.

Comment: @matt Great to know, thanks for sharing that. I will need to review my app's usage metrics to see if it's worth supporting iOS 12 and below.

Comment: A custom property wrapper could be useful. See [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/), "Property Wrappers in Swift | Swift by Sundell" for details

Comment: Are all of these settings changed from within a single view controller or can the user modify these settings throughout the app?

Comment: @bsod Nearly all of them are set within a single view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If all (or almost all) of these settings are changed from within a single view controller, then I wouldn't consider the KVO model or dropping OS support for a newer framework because your problem is really much simpler than that which deserves a much simpler solution.

You shouldn't care about the individual value changes of these settings because that would mean you care about updating the database every time the user changes one. Even in spite of Firestore's pricing model, that's not efficient. What you should care about is when the user is done with the view controller did any values change—and if they did then you want to update the database, underneath the user (they don't need to wait or tap on a save button because Firestore is offline capable).

Therefore, when the user opens this view controller, just record the current values of these settings in the view controller itself (maybe in `viewDidLoad`), and when the user leaves the view controller, check if any of the values changed (maybe in `viewWillDisappear`)—and if so, update the database.